# SpriteKit Shader not running with Uniforms

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, sprite-kit, shader

*// Posting this up in case anyone comes across the same problem.*

## Original Problem:

Porting a shader over to OSX, and attempting to feed it a uniform. The shader doesn't actually run.

This is on: XCode 7.3 , Swift 2 .

GameScene.swift :

```
var myShader = SKShader();

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //////////////////////////////////
    // Create SKShader
    let shaderContainer = SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300));
    shaderContainer.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2);

    self.addChild(shaderContainer);

    myShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "color-wheel.fsh");
    let utest = SKUniform(name: "utest", float: 0.3);
    myShader.addUniform(utest);

    shaderContainer.shader = myShader;
}
```

color-wheel.fsh (Shader):

```
#define PI 3.14159265359
#define TWO_PI 6.28318530718

//  Function from Iñigo Quiles
//  https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsS3Wc
vec3 hsb2rgb( in vec3 c ){
    vec3 rgb = clamp(abs(mod(c.x*6.0+vec3(0.0,4.0,2.0), 6.0)-3.0)-1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    rgb = rgb*rgb*(3.0-2.0*rgb);
    return c.z * mix(vec3(1.0), rgb, c.y);
}

void main (void) {
    vec2 st = v_tex_coord; // SPRITEKIT SPECIFIC

    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    // Using Polar Coordinates instead of Cartesian
    vec2 vectorToCentre = vec2(0.5) - st;
    float angle = atan(vectorToCentre.y, vectorToCentre.x); // function is atan(y,x) , not x,y
    float distanceToCentre = length(vectorToCentre);
    float radius = distanceToCentre * 2.0;
    angle = angle + u_time*0.6 - radius*2.5;

    vec3 hue = vec3(angle/TWO_PI+0.5, radius, 1.0) * vec3(1.0, 0.4, 1.0);
    color = hsb2rgb(hue);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Found this after a bit of trialing.*

## Solution:

In this scenario (XCode 7.3), it appears if a shader utilises uniforms, and #defines, the #defines must not be on the zeroth line, e.g.;

color-wheel.fsh (Shader):

```
// BLANK LINE HERE
#define PI 3.14159265359
#define TWO_PI 6.28318530718

...
```

I imagine iOS may also require similar consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are never declaring a uniform in your shader. Somewhere in the shader you should have

```
uniform float utest
```

I suspect you got confused with utest and u_time, which is a built in glsl uniform on ios

edit: Actually, I am wrong. You do not have to declare uniforms in ios when you set them. In fact, if you do, they break the shader. So in your case the bug is you are declaring a uniform with the wrong name (eg, uniform name not used in shader)